# What are the rules for contract workers on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, employment

This summer I’m working as a camp counselor at a non Jewish camp that would have me working during Shabbos, however I’m not sure any of my responsibilities actually violate Shabbos. My main job is to supervise a group of children and run activities for them, mostly sports and games, however I am being paid to be there. I’m paid a fixed salary based on a two week contract, not by the day. Is it possible to observe Shabbos in this situation? Please let me know any relevant Halakha.

Comment: This type of job presents numerous Halachic issues. Some of these issues might include (but not limited to) kosher food, daily prayers, general Shabbos observance (speaking on a microphone, carrying on campgrounds), mixed swimming, mingling of the sexes, and physical contact with members of the opposite sex. As with all life situations, the laws of Yichud apply too. You should run these issues by a rabbi who you can discuss these matters in detail.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?